# How do I store data to one object in Android for the whole app to access

Tags: java, android, singleton

I'm utilizing Firebase in my application and I figure it'd be better practice if I constantly observed the AuthState once the user has signed up or logged in and updated one class that can be accessed globally throughout my application (but that can only be instantiated once). Do I use a Singleton design pattern for this? How do I accomplish something like this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to create your own subclass of Android's `Application` class (specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` as shown below for example) and store variable there....effectively a singleton.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app I use a static way for doing something similar.. maybe it helps to find solution for your situation:

I created a class which can not be instantiated because the constructor is set `private` and the class is used as some "variable-holder" accessible from all app statically. Here is the class:
`VarHolder.java`

```
package your.package.name;

public class VarHolder {
    private VarHolder() {}

    static int myInt;
    static String myString;
}
```

than in app I use it this way:

```
VarHolder.myInt = 1;
VarHolder.myString = "Hello";
```

on another place in app :

```
textView.setText(VarHolder.myString);
```